ubuntu 24.04 - Cannot change "enterprise" account password after unlock
I upgraded my ubuntu version to 24.04 and since then I am unable to change my password from the gnome settings page.
Inputs are disabled and tells me to unlock to get access to this option.
Never got issues with this before.
I am not the administrator of the ldap server but could change my password without privileges (except for the initial setup to get in the realm).
Disclaimer: I am not very familiar with ldap but I am ready to try ideas.
Things I tried:

ldapasswd but it asked for the admin password
config ldap didn't work even after reboot



Edit 20/11/2024:
I noticed I had a service related to the authentication process that was failing "sssd_pac"
I found a documentation from redhat related to it.
Here are my logs:
(2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [server_setup] (0x3f7c0): Starting with debug level = 0x0070
(2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sbus_dbus_request_name] (0x0020): Unable to request name on the system bus [3]
(2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_dp_init] (0x0010): Failed to connect to backend server.
********************** PREVIOUS MESSAGE WAS TRIGGERED BY THE FOLLOWING BACKTRACE:
   *  [pac] [server_setup] (0x0080): Failed setting process group: Operation not permitted[1]. We might leak processes in case of failure
   *  [pac] [ldb] (0x0400): server_sort:Unable to register control with rootdse!
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [server_setup] (0x0400): CONFDB: /var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [schedule_responder_idle_timer] (0x2000): Re-scheduling the idle timeout [responder_idle_timeout] for the responder [0x5b19dab74fc0]
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [setup_responder_idle_timer] (0x2000): Setting up the idle timeout [responder_idle_timeout] for the responder [0x5b19dab74fc0]
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [confdb_init_domain_provider_and_enum] (0x0400): No enumeration for [<<realm>>]!
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [confdb_init_domain_provider_and_enum] (0x0400): Please note that when enumeration is disabled `getent passwd` does not return all users by design. See sssd.conf man page for more detailed information
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [confdb_init_domain_pwd_expire] (0x1000): pwd_expiration_warning is -1
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/sh in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/bash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /usr/bin/bash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/rbash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /usr/bin/rbash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /usr/bin/sh in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /bin/dash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /usr/bin/dash in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_get_etc_shells] (0x0400): Found shell /usr/bin/tmux in /etc/shells
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_names_init_from_args] (0x0100): Using re [^(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+))|((?P<name>.+)@(?P<domain>[^@]+))|((?P<name>[^@\\]+)))$].
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_fqnames_init] (0x0100): Using fq format [%1$s@%2$s].
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_dp_init] (0x0010): Failed to connect to backend server.
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error setting up backend connector
(2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [pac_process_init] (0x0010): sss_process_init() failed
********************** PREVIOUS MESSAGE WAS TRIGGERED BY THE FOLLOWING BACKTRACE:
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_process_init] (0x0010): fatal error setting up backend connector
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [sss_responder_ctx_destructor] (0x0400): Responder is being shut down
   *  (2024-11-15  9:52:15): [pac] [pac_process_init] (0x0010): sss_process_init() failed


I have the same issue.
I tried playing with polkit but the password change is still grayed out.
[User Passwd]
Identity=*
Action=org.freedesktop.accounts.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes


The unlock button prompts for an admin user, not the logged-in user.
If I unlock with the admin user, the password is still grayed out.
